# Changing textcolor in Yii2 with material bootstrap library doesnt work

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to change the color of texts or even the background of the footer (for example) but after add [this library](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/), everything is changed and i can't even change the color of a text.

This is my **MaterialAsset**:

```
<?php
/**
 * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
 * @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
 */

namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class MaterialAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@themes/material';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/material.min.css',
        'css/material-fullpalette.min.css',
        'css/ripples.min.css',
        'css/roboto.min.css',
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/material.min.js',
        'js/ripples.min.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

And i'm trying to use this in my **site.css**:

```
html,
.footer {
    height: 180px;
    background-color: #222222;
    border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.customtext {

    color: white;
}

.wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto -60px;
    padding: 0 0 60px;
}

.wrap > .container {
    padding: 70px 15px 20px;
}

.not-set {
    color: #c55;
    font-style: italic;
}

/* add sorting icons to gridview sort links */
a.asc:after, a.desc:after {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings', fantasy;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

a.asc:after {
    content: /*"\e113"*/ "\e151";
}

a.desc:after {
    content: /*"\e114"*/ "\e152";
}

.sort-numerical a.asc:after {
    content: "\e153";
}

.sort-numerical a.desc:after {
    content: "\e154";
}

.sort-ordinal a.asc:after {
    content: "\e155";
}

.sort-ordinal a.desc:after {
    content: "\e156";
}

.grid-view th {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.hint-block {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: #999;
}

.error-summary {
    color: #a94442;
    background: #fdf7f7;
    border-left: 3px solid #eed3d7;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}
```

about this line or even that footer.

```
.customtext {

    color: white;
}
```

and after adding in my index:

```
<p class="text-success customtext">News</p>
```

But this doesn't work at all.

How can i change the color of this text or the footer color in this application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't in other way you can only try with an inline style like this

```
 <p style="color: white;">News</p>
```

Comment: it's working without this `customtext`.i just edited the answer because of the text-success and now it's working.tnx :)